# OpenDKIM: Use MySQL socket in KeyTable/SigningTable

Tags: opendkim

How can i connect to a MySQL socket (not TCP) with e.g. KeyTable/SigningTable in OpenDKIM?

The dataset which needs to be used is "dsn:" and the manual says:

> If the string begins with "dsn:" and the OpenDKIM library was compiled
>   to support that database type, then the remainder of the string is a
>   Data Store Name describing the type, location parameters and access
>   credentials for an ODBC or SQL database. The DSN is of the form:
>   backend://[user[:pwd]@][port+]host/dbase[/key=value[?...]]
>
> where backend is the name of a supported backend database mechanism
>   (e.g. "mysql"), user and password are optional login credentials for
>   the database, port and host describe the destination of a TCP
>   connection to connect to that database, dbase is the name of the
>   database to be accessed, and the key=value pairs must specify at least
>   "table", "keycol" and "datacol" values specifying the name of the
>   table, the name of the column to consider as the key, and the name(s)
>   of the column(s) to be considered as the values (separated by commas).
>   For example (all in one line):
>
> mysql:://dbuser:dbpass@3306+dbhost/odkim/table=macros
>   ?keycol=host?datacol=v1,v2
>
> defines a MySQL database listening at port 3306 on host "dbhost"; the
>   userid "dbuser" and password "dbpass" should be used to access the
>   database; the database name is "odkim", and the data are in columns
>   "host" (the keys) and "v1" and "v2" (the values) inside table
>   "macros". This example would thus return two values when a match is
>   found.
>
> No value within the DSN may contain any of the six punctuation
>   characters (":", "/", "@", "+", "?" and "=") used to separate portions
>   of the DSN from each other.

It seems it's not possible to connect to MySQL socket, but only via TCP?

Comment: Check the `#ifdef USE_ODBX` part of `opendkim-db.c`.. I do not see any way.

Answer (score 0):

OpenDKIM [uses](https://github.com/trusteddomainproject/OpenDKIM/blob/rel-opendkim-2-10-3/opendkim/opendkim-db.c#L1281) OpenDBX library to connect to backend databases, including MySQL; and currently only [OpenDBX 1.2+ supports UNIX sockets for MySQL](https://www.linuxnetworks.de/doc/index.php?title=OpenDBX/C_API/odbx_init#Description). OpenDBX 1.1 [only support UNIX sockets for PostgreSQL](https://linuxnetworks.de/doc/index.php?title=OpenDBX/C_API/odbx_init&oldid=2815#Description).

Furthermore, OpenDKIM limits its configurations to use DSN strings, requiring it to [parse DSN string](https://github.com/trusteddomainproject/OpenDKIM/blob/rel-opendkim-2-10-3/opendkim/opendkim-db.c#L2536) into its components (`host`, `port`, `database`, ...).

Even though it's possible for OpenDBX to use UNIX sockets to connect to MySQL, even in the latest `master` (20220402) branch, OpenDKIM expects `/` character (after DSN backend) as a [separator between host+port and database name](https://github.com/trusteddomainproject/OpenDKIM/blob/5c539587561785a66c1f67f720f2fb741f320785/opendkim/opendkim-db.c#L2630), not an UNIX socket path component. Using DSN value like this:

```
mysql://user:pass@3306+/path/to/mysql.socket/odkim/table=macros?keycol=host?datacol=v1,v2
```

should result an empty hostname (`dsn->dsn_host`) and OpenDKIM return an error.

Probably open an issue on [their Github page](https://github.com/trusteddomainproject/OpenDKIM) to raise this concern to the developers.

Answer (score -2):

I've just setup OpenDKIM to connect to MySQL on its socket.

First, create the user `opendkim` in MySQL Server :

```
CREATE USER 'opendkim'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket;
GRANT SELECT ON opendkim.* TO 'opendkim'@'localhost';
```

And add these lines in opendkim config file (/etc/opendkim.conf on Debian) :

```
SigningTable dsn:mysql://localhost/opendkim/table=dkim?keycol=domain_name?datacol=id
KeyTable     dsn:mysql://localhost/opendkim/table=dkim?keycol=id?datacol=domain_name,selector,private_key
```

As you can see, you only have to define the hostname of the MySQL server (no user, no password) : `localhost`.

Configuration :

- Debian 11
- OpenDKIM 2.11.0 (installed from apt)
- libopendbx1-mysql 1.4.6
- MariaDB Server 10.5.15

Comment: it lacks a lot on supporting information IMHO. and why does opendkim needs to be a superuser?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).